# Sort a date from further away in time to closer, starting from the current date

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I want to have a function that sorts dates from further away in time to closer to the current date, but starting from this current date, so that it doesn't list the ones that are already in the past.

I have this function:

```
const sortBySoonestDate = (a,b) => {
    
        const dateA = new Date(a.date);
        const dateB = new Date(b.date);
        if (a.date > b.date) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.date < b.date) {
            return -1;
        }


        return 0;
    }
```

This already works for sorting the dates, but doesn't take into account the current date, so it also doesn't work to rule out the past ones.

The expected result I want is for the list of dates to be sorted STARTING on the current date, and ignore the past ones.

E.g.: Today is 13/09/2023 so the list should be:

[14/09/2023,15/09/2023]

and should ignore dates such as:

[11/09/2023,12/09/2023]

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorting and filtering are two different things, so don't mix them together. Handle each individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter first, then sort:

```js
const data = Array.from({length: 30}, (_, i, dt) => ({date: '2023-09-' + (i+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')})).reverse();

console.log(...data.map(JSON.stringify));

const now = new Date;
const today = now.getFullYear() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + now.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

console.log('Today:', today);

const sorted = data.filter(({date}) => date >= today).sort(({date:a}, {date:b}) => a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1);

console.log(...sorted.map(JSON.stringify));
```

Comment: How could I apply this to an array that comes from the store in flux? I was trying the .filter() method but wasn't really working, probably because of a grammatical mistake I don't understand since I'm pretty much a beginner.
I was trying this:
`const classesByDate = store.classes;

 let today = new Date();

 let futureClasses = classesByDate.filter(futureFilter(date));

 const futureFilter = (date) => {
  return date >= today
 }`

It gives me the "futureFIlter is not a function" error in the console

Comment: @Zerkley i need your array. maybe dates are strings in your data... should be converted to dates first

Comment: Sorry, it's an object with a property "date", which is the one I want to use, this is the content of the object:
{
            "comments": "",
            "date": "2023-09-20",
            "hour": "17:00",
            "id": 1,
            "paid": false,
            "price": 20.0,
}
Date is a string in the data yes, I would have to convert it

Comment: @Zerkley fixed... if my answer solves your problem don't forget to accept it (the checkbox)

Comment: @Zerkley an error: add date to a and b in sort